# Power Bi - Solver Function

Tags: python, excel, algorithm, powerbi, solver

I have a problem which works to a degree in Excel using solver. However, I do not know how it can be done within Power BI*

What I essentially want to do is distribute/reallocate volume across several categories.

Example:

I have 5 warehouses all working at different productivity efficiencies.

- Warehouse A = 90 throughput rate per hour - Max Capacity 1,200,000
- Warehouse B = 85 throughput rate per hour - Max Capacity 800,000
- Warehouse C = 100 throughput rate per hour - Max Capacity 2,200,00
- Warehouse D = 75 throughput rate per hour - Max Capacity 1,000,000
- Warehouse E = 95 throughput rate per hour - Max Capacity 1,100,000

I have 5,000,000 units of volume that I need to distribute to these 5 warehouses. The idea is to reduce cost so the most efficient warehouse should get as much of this volume until it hits its maximum capacity after which it moves to the warehouse with the second best throughput rate.
So in this example Warehouse C will get allocated as much volume as it can take before they hit their max capacity. Then it will move to warehouse E, then Warehouse A. The algorithm should stop as soon as the 5,000,000 units are used up.

(Cost is calculated using the cost per labor hour £15. i.e Volume (units) / Throughput rate = Hours ; Hours * £15 = £ Cost)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This seems very unclear: you say it is solved with Excel and the Solver, but then it is not solved. What do you expect? A solution without Solver? Then vba... I would use the Solver for this anyway.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SolarMike - Sorry was a typo. it solves in Excel using the solver, however i dont know how to replicate the solver function in powerbi.

Answer (score 0):

You can run R scripts from Power BI. There are R packages to model and solve problems like this. I would start by developing a mathematical model for this problem. That makes it easier to select a suitable package.